# Create variable on household level based on individual conditions?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to create a new dichotomous variable column (1/0; Yes/No) based on if **anyone** within a household (marked by a household ID number) is 1 or 2 in one column (`var1`) **AND** indicated 1 (Yes) for a different column (`var3`)?

This is the code I've tried. I am able to mutate a new column based on the individuals but not on the household level. As of now, `new_dichotomous` is 1 only if for an individual `var1` is equal to 1 or 2 and `var3` is 1. I need it to be if anyone within the household's`var1` is equal to 1 or 2 and `var3` is 1 then the value for `new_dichotomous` is 1 for the everyone in the household (those with the same householdID).

```
 dataset %>%
      group_by(householdID) %>%
      mutate(new_dichotomous = if_else(var1 == 1 |
                                       var1 == 2 & any(var3 == 1), 1, 0))
```

Comment: You could use `mutate(new_dichotomous = +(any(c(1, 2) %in% var1) & 1 %in% var3))`

Comment: Thank you! I think that worked – how do I make sure NAs are kept as NAs in the new variable?

Comment: Try the solution below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We may use

```
library(dplyr)
 dataset %>%
      group_by(householdID) %>%
      mutate(new_dichotomous = +(any(c(1, 2) %in% var1) & 1 %in% var3) * 
           NA^(if_any(c(var1, var2, var3), is.na))) %>%
      ungroup
```